# Security risks tied to iOS push notification certificate

Tags: ios, security, apple-push-notifications

I have a security question related to iOS push notification certificates.  When I export the certificate as a p12 and share it with say Google Cloud Messaging, what potential risks are there if someone gets a hold of that p12 file?  I guess it's possible someone wanting to be malicious could crack the password associated with the p12 and gain access to the push notification cert, but they would also need valid device push tokens generated from my app in order to send any “hacked” push notifications to my app users, correct?  Is this the only risk, or is there other information on that p12 file I should be concerned with?

I realize that Apple now offers another approach with the use of push notification keys, and that may be the better approach, but for now I’m just trying to understand the potential risks the push certificate may have if in the “wrong hands”.

Answer (score 0):

They could run this command to extract the private key from the p12 container:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

Comment: So what could someone then do with the private key once extracted?

Comment: Leaked secret keys allow the attacker to decrypt any past and future traffic to the protected services and to impersonate the service at will. Any protection given by the encryption and the signatures in the X.509 certificates can be bypassed. Recovery from this leak requires patching the vulnerability, revocation of the compromised keys and reissuing and redistributing new keys.

Comment: Just to be clear the scope of the services at risk would be limited to the push notifications services?  Someone could potentially intercept our request to send the notification and use that information to hijack the request and view any data that is part of the it?  They could also use that intercepted request to create their own push notifications to send out on our behalf?  If all requests are sent via secure (https) connections, is the risk of all this happening pretty small or something that should be a concern when considering to use the certificate route for push notifications?